# When doing a 2 query it does not search the database again

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

At the moment of executing the bot if it performs its operation correctly the first time, but later it does not consult the database again or continues to the cycle for "for idTelegram, Trunk in cur.fetchall() :"

Database connection

```
#Conexion a Base de Datos Para validacion
miConexion = mysql.connector.connect( host='localhost', user= 'root', passwd='', db='validacion' )
cur = miConexion.cursor()
cur = miConexion.cursor(buffered=True)
cur.execute( "SELECT idTelegram, Troncal FROM troncales" )
```

Telegram messages start and update functions

```
#Token de Telegram
updater = Updater(token="")
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


ConsultarSaldoSw2 = "Consultar Saldo SW2"

def startCommand(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    buttons = [[KeyboardButton(ConsultarSaldoSw2)]]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Bienvenido", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

def messageHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    
    bot = context.bot
    updateMsg = getattr(update, 'message', None)
    messageId = updateMsg.message_id
    chatId = update.message.chat_id
    userName = update.effective_user['username']
    text = update.message.text


    
    if ConsultarSaldoSw2 in update.message.text:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Ingresa tu Nombre de Troncal")
        return text
    
    
    print (text)
```

At this point it is no longer executed when another request is sent through telegram

```
for idTelegram, Troncal in cur.fetchall() :
   print ("prueba")
   
   
   if userName in idTelegram:
       if text in Troncal:
         print ("Troncal Correcta "+ text)
         Saldo = client.getAccountInfo({ 'username':  (text)})
         SaldoESP1 = (f"{Saldo['balance']}")
         TroncalCompleta = (f"{Saldo['authname']}")
         Moneda = (f"{Saldo['base_currency']}")
         print (Saldo)

         integer = float(SaldoESP1)
         if integer < 0:
             Convertir = integer * -1
             print (Convertir)
             Convertir = str(Convertir)
             context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= TroncalCompleta + " es "  + Convertir +" "+ Moneda )
             break
         elif integer > 0:
             Convertir = integer * -1
             print (Convertir)
             Convertir = str(Convertir)
             context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= TroncalCompleta + " es "  + Convertir +" "+ Moneda )
             break
       else:
         print ("Troncal Incorrecto "+text)
         context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="No estas permitido para ver esto" )
         break
   else:
       print ("Usuario Incorrecto "+userName)
       context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Usuario Incorrecto Validalo con soporte" )
       break
cur.reset()
```

```
 dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", startCommand))
 dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, messageHandler))
 updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: You can't call `fetchall()` for the same query multiple times. `fetchall()` fetches all the rows that haven't yet been fetched. If you call it a second time, there's nothing to fetch. If you want to loop through the results multiple times, assign the result to variable and use that.

Comment: Could you help me with an example of how it would be please?

Comment: `rows = cur.fetchall()`. Then you can do `for idTelegram, Troncal in in rows:`

Comment: When testing with the fetchall I see that it reads the entire database, I would like to know if it is possible or if there is a method to return only the data with which it matches.

Because if I let it run completely, it returns the wrong data with the message "print ("Incorrect User")" and the correct data.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That depends entirely on the query. If you only want to return a subset, use `WHERE` conditions that restrict it.

Comment: thanks, but how can I do the where query if I'm doing the validation with data that I get externally.

As the data "userName" and "text" in which I get the values of the telegram id and the trunk.

SELECT idTelegram, Trunk FROM trunks

Comment: `SELECT idTelegram, Trunk FROM trunks WHERE username = %s and Trunk LIKE %s` and then use the externally-provided data as parameters in `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro  :)